# django-allauth change user email with/without verification

Tags: django, email, django-allauth

I am using plain django-allauth without any social accounts. Every user should have exactly one email address associated with his account, i.e. the one that was used for registration/verification. I would like to enable my users to change this email.

So my first question is, should I have the new email being verified again by sending out the verifcation email? My gut feeling says, I better have this new email being verified. But I have no real arguments for that.

My second question is, if if want that to be verified, is that process somehow supported already with django-allauth? I have seen the EmailView and AddEmailForm. But those are based on the assumption that one account can have more than 1 email address (which is not what I want).

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the [`EmailView`](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py#L209) and the [`AddEmailForm`](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/forms.py#L277).

Comment: Thanks elssar, just updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways you could go about doing this.

Either listen to the [`email_confirmed`](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/signals.py#L12) signal handler, and have a function that checks whether user has two `EmailAccount` objects associated with his account, and if so, delete the other `EmailAccount` object.

The other would be set `EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL` and `EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL` in your settings and have related view delete the extra email address, if it exists.

Another way would be to just override the `EmailView` and/or `AddEmailForm` and have them do what you want.

For changing email without confirmation, you could just have your view call the [`EmailAddress.change`](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/models.py#L59) method.

Comment: When we use `EmailAddress.change`, `email_changed` signal should be fired ? Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @Prakhar I haven't used allauth in ages so I might be wrong, but from a quick scan of the code it seems like the `email_changed` signal is fired when the user changes their primary email from one email object to another. `EmailAddress.change` changes the value of the email in the same object.

Answer (score 19):

I think the new email address should be verified. If your application sends periodic emails, you don't want to fire off loads of emails to just any email address that a user enters.

What I did was allow multiple email addresses until the second email is verified. Then, listen for django-allauth's `email_confirmed` signal as elssar suggested. As soon as the address is verified, set the new email address as the primary email, then delete any previous `EmailAddess`. Here's a simplified example of what I ended up doing:

models:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from allauth.account.models import EmailAddress
from allauth.account.signals import email_confirmed

class CustomUser(models.Model):
    ...
    def add_email_address(self, request, new_email):
        # Add a new email address for the user, and send email confirmation.
        # Old email will remain the primary until the new one is confirmed.
        return EmailAddress.objects.add_email(request, self.user, new_email, confirm=True)

@receiver(email_confirmed)
def update_user_email(sender, request, email_address, **kwargs):
    # Once the email address is confirmed, make new email_address primary.
    # This also sets user.email to the new email address.
    # email_address is an instance of allauth.account.models.EmailAddress
    email_address.set_as_primary()
    # Get rid of old email addresses
    stale_addresses = EmailAddress.objects.filter(
        user=email_address.user).exclude(primary=True).delete()
```

views:

```
def update_user_details(request):
    user = request.user
    new_email = request.POST.get('new_email')
    user.custom_user.add_email_address(request, new_email)
    ...
```

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but it seems to me that all you need to do, to implement a single email address, is the imports, and the code from ```@receiver…``` down in ```models```. ie you don’t need the ```CustomUser``` model or code in ```views```

Comment: @typonaut You can have a single email address with less work, but this solution also you to  update the email address while still preventing the user from keeping multiple emails